# TeraTermのコマンドラインオプションの指定方法について

Tags: teraterm

以下の画像のような選択をしたのと同等の状態でTeraTermを起動するショートカットを作成したいのですが、TeraTermのコマンドラインオプション指定する方法をご存じの方がいましたらご教示いただけないでしょうか？

ホスト名とポート番号は以下のように指定すればよいと思うのですが、

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" localhost:22

それ以外のオプション：

- サービス＝その他
- プロトコル＝UNSPEC

の指定方法について本家マニュアルを見てもわかりませんでした。

参照した本家マニュアル：
https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/commandline/teraterm.html

[image: TeraTerm起動オプション]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### バージョン

Tera Termのバージョンは何ですか? `プロトコル: UNSPEC` になっているという事は最新のバージョンでは無いはずです。(最新版では`IPバージョン: AUTO`)
以下に書く内容はかなり古めのバージョンでも通用するはずですが、うまく行かなかった場合は使っているバージョンを教えてください。

#### サービス: その他

これはちょっと判りづらいですね。TELNETで無い([/T=0](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/commandline/teraterm.html#t))、かつSSHでない([/nossh](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/commandline/ttssh.html#nossh))時にその他になります。
なので`/T=0`と`/nossh`の両方を指定すればいい事になるのですが、実は`/T=0`を指定すると[SSHも無効](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/commandline/ttssh.html#t)になります。
つまり`/T=0`のみを追加すればOKです。

#### プロトコル: UNSPEC (IPバージョン: AUTO)

`/4`や`/6`でIPv4やIPv6だけに限定していない場合にIPバージョンが`UNSPEC(AUTO)`になります。
なので、`/4`と`/6`の両方とも指定していなければ特別にオプションを追加しなくても`AUTO`になります。

というわけで、最終的にはコマンドラインを以下のようにすれば大丈夫なはずです。

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" localhost:22 /T=0
```

Comment: バージョンは4.103だったので最新ではありませんでした。ご教示いただいた方法で期待通りのオプションで起動できました。ありがとうございました。